# Reading optional white spaces in sscanf()

Tags: c, ansi-c

So i have been working on an C project and im stuck on this problem, basically Im making a program where the user can enter their name and I later print it out to a file, the first and last name of the user is split with a comma however, optional whitespace in around the comma is allowed. This is what i have been using the read the user names:

```
    char lastName[20]; 
    char firstName[20]; 
    char line[LINESIZE]; 
    while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,stdin)) { 
       if((sscanf(line," %s , %s ",lastName,firstName)) == 2)  { 
             /*process name */
       } 
    }
```

However, the only time it reads input successfully is when the user inputs:

```
john , doe
```

which matches the %s , %s I have, how can i make it such that something like:

```
john, doe 
john ,doe
```

Can all work?

I have also tried

```
sscanf(line,"%s%[],%[]%s");
```

This doesnt cause compilation error, but it doesnt process input meaning it doesnt match the %s , %s

Comment: You will find this easier to accomplish using `strtok`.

Comment: @zwol: `sscanf` and friends has a lot of quirls, `strtok` is broken in its own ways... just parse the string by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will isolate the names so that any permutation of `"Doe  , John"` filters out the whitespace

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINESIZE 100

int main(void) {
    char lastName[20] = {0}; 
    char firstName[20] = {0}; 
    char line[LINESIZE]; 
    char *first = NULL, *last = NULL;
    if (NULL == fgets(line,LINESIZE,stdin))
        return 1;
    last = strtok (line, ", \t\r\n");
    if (last)
        first = strtok (NULL, ", \t\r\n");

    if (last && first) {
        sprintf(firstName, "%.19s", first);
        sprintf(lastName, "%.19s", last);
        printf ("%s %s\n", firstName, lastName);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not encourage the use of `strncpy`.  Also note that multiple commas will be skipped by `strtok()`, including at the beginning of `line`. This may be a little too flexible.

Comment: @chqrlie I've replaced the `strncpy` which also removes the need to initialise `firstName`  and `lastName` (because `strncpy` does not append a `'\0'` when the buffer size is reached).

Comment: You should use `snprintf` to avoid the hard coded `%.19s`.  `sprintf` is error prone too;-)

Comment: @chqrlie I wish I had left that out now and stuck to my original `printf ("%s %s\n", first, last);` to show `strtok()`, omitting his (hard-coded) 20-length strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the `sscanf` format to have it perform a more stringent test:

```
char eol[2];
if (sscanf(line, " %19[a-zA-Z-] , %19[a-zA-Z-]%1[\n]", lastName, firstName, eol) == 3) ...
```

`sscanf` will verify that the user typed exactly 2 words made of letters separated by a comma and optional spaces and followed by a line feed.

But I strongly encourage you to parse the input yourself instead of relying on `sscanf`.  It is not difficult, much more precise and flexible, and less error prone:

```
char lastName[LINESIZE];
char firstName[LINESIZE]; 
char line[LINESIZE]; 
while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,stdin)) {
   char *p = line, *q;
   while (isspace((unsigned char)*p)) p++;
   for (q = lastName; isalpha((unsigned char)*p); p++) {
       *q++ = *p;
   }
   *q = '\0';
   while (isspace((unsigned char)*p)) p++;
   if (*p == ',') p++;
   while (isspace((unsigned char)*p)) p++;
   for (q = firstName; isalpha((unsigned char)*p); p++) {
       *q++ = *p;
   }
   *q = '\0';
   while (isspace((unsigned char)*p)) p++;
   if (*lastName && *firstName && !*p) {
       // format is OK
       printf("Hello %s %s\n", firstName, lastName);
   } 
}
```

Comment: If you know you are limited to spaces, you can avoid the function call simply reading the last name with `while (*p != ' ' || *p != ',')`, then read `while  (*p == ' ' || *p == ',')` to skip intervening spaces and comma, and then finish with `strcpy (firstname, p)`. (you can also `strlen` and `strncpy` if you are protecting against a malicious first name.). `strchr (p, ',')` can also be used to jump to the comma and test `if (p - 1  == ' ')` and then set a temporary `\n` reading `lastName` from `line` and so on.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: Thank you for your suggestions, but the first loop is incorrect (`||` instead of `&&` and not testing `'\0'`), the second would accept multiple `','` which I consider incorrect, the `strcpy` would not check for letters and accept more than one word. `strncpy` is a bad idea to protect from malicious input because of its counterintuitive semantics, jumping to `','` with `strchr` would not check for letters and the `' '` before it is optional... I would favor an inline function to skip spaces, and another one to skip letters.

Comment: I stand corrected `:p` Good catch. I agree with with your `strncpy` assessment, that is why I dropped it as a note in my comment. With `strchr` since you are reading a string, it was presumed you would pass it to `strtol` where any non-digit issues would be resolved. I prefer just walking the pointer down the string which allows complete control over rejecting preceding characters if you choose.